# Google Maps iOS SDK. How to hide a marker label when overlapping another marker?

Tags: objective-c, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios

I’m looking to replicate the behavior of the Google Maps app, where labels are dynamically hidden if they overlap other labels or icons.

Like this:

[Both labels showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50e3W.png)

[One label showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQBCE.png)

My current setup is a GMSMapView with GMSMarkers that have custom icons (UIImages):

[Custom marker and label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfTDS.png)

Since the SDK doesn’t provide a way to add textlabels to markers, marker and label are as grouped as a UIImage like this :

```
    let label = UILabel() //simplified
    let iconView = UIImageView //simplified
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(label.frame.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
    if let currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            iconView.layer.render(in: currentContext)
            let iconAndLabel = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            marker.icon = iconAndLabel
        }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Comment: I need similar functionality to hide names only when overlap. Have you done this?

Comment: @Mudassir, did you find any solution ?

Comment: @aqsaarshad Not yet. I'm hiding label on a certain zoom level for now.